# How does cross-thread collection updating work?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's a toy example, in which updating an ObservableHashSet from a different thread sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

- It definitely doesn't work when the collection is bound to the UI. But the exception message is clearly a lie because:
- it doesn't crash if it has never been bound.
- But it crashes if you bind first and then remove the binding.

Why does Add(4) work while Add(6) crashes?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace ObservableThreadTester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = new Vm();
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //this does not crash
                vm.Set.Add(4);
            });

            DataContext = vm;
            vm.Set.Add(5);
            DataContext = null;

            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //this crashes with "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread"
                vm.Set.Add(6);
            });
        }
    }

    public class Vm
    {
        public ObservableHashSet<int> Set { get; set; } = new ObservableHashSet<int>();
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableThreadTester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="195*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="239*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Set}" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" Content="click me"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: When you call Add(4) vm is not bound to the DataContext of the view, but when you call Add(6) vm is bound to the ListBox and this call must be done from the UI thread since it updates the UI.

Comment: Wrap the Add(6) call with this.BeginInvoke to call it on the UI thread.

Comment: Note the DataContext = null; line. The collection is no longer bound.

Comment: You could also use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5274751/Understanding-the-SynchronizationContext-in-NET-wi